# Angular Form not submitting on first click

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have built a small angular App into my website whereby a user enters a searchterm into an input field and then values are returned via an Angular service. When I attempt to submit a value however, the form does not submit and will only submit on the 2nd attempt. I cannot figure out why this is happening.
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-app="clubFilter" class="col-lg-12">
<div class="col-lg-3">

</div>
<div class="col-lg-9" ng-controller="clubController">       
    <form ng-submit="filterClubs()">
        <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <ul class="leisure-centres">            
        <li ng-repeat="club in clubs">              
            <div class="centre">
                <a class="link" ng-href="{club.link}">More info</a>
                <div class="image" ng-show="club.image > 0">
                    <img src="{{image}}" alt="{{club.title}}" />                        
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                    <div class="title">
                        <h3>{{club.title}}<span ng-show="club.distance > 0"> - {{club.distance}} miles away</span></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="address">
                        {{club.building}},
                        {{club.street}},
                        {{club.city}},
                        {{club.county}},
                        {{club.postcode}}                           
                    </div>
                    <div class="tel">
                        <strong>Tel: </strong>
                        <a href="tel:{{club.telephone}}" ng-bind="club.telephone"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="email">
                        <strong>Email: </strong>
                        <a href="mailto:{{club.email}}" ng-bind="club.email"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>           
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
var JSONItems = <?php echo $this->JSONItems; ?>;    
var searchTerm = "<?php echo $this->searchTerm; ?>";
```

And here is my angular controller

```
angular.module('clubFilter.controllers', []).
controller('clubController', function($scope, $http, googleMapService) {
    $scope.keyWord = "SEARCH";
    $scope.clubsJSON = JSONItems;   
    if(searchTerm == "") {          
        $scope.clubs = $scope.clubsJSON;        
    } else {
        $scope.searchTerm = searchTerm;     
        googleMapService.setLatLng($scope.searchTerm, $scope.clubsJSON).then(function(sortedArray) {            
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                $scope.clubs = sortedArray;                 
            });         
        }, function(err) {
            alert("no");
        });         
    }       

    $scope.filterClubs = function() {       
        googleMapService.setLatLng($scope.searchTerm, $scope.clubsJSON).then(function(sortedArray) {                
            $scope.clubs = sortedArray; 
        }, function(err) {
            alert("no");
        });
    }       
});
```

As far as I am aware I have everything defined as it should be?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one;

```
<div class="col-lg-9" ng-controller="clubController as club">       
    <form ng-submit="club.filterClubs()">
        <input type="text" name="location" ng-model="club.searchTerm" placeholder="Search..." />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

And in your controller;

```
this.filterClubs = function() {       
    googleMapService.setLatLng(this.searchTerm, $scope.clubsJSON).then(function(sortedArray) {                
        $scope.clubs = sortedArray; 
    }, function(err) {
        alert("no");
    });
}
```